# Should the name of bean id and the reference name be same always in springs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I am digging into Springs framework recently and just came up with a small question. 
Suppose if we have a class like this:

```
class A
{
    @Autowired
    private B hello;
    ....
    ....
}
```

and in the xml file I have defined like this:

```
<bean id="abc" class="org.eclipse.packageName.B"/>
```

Should the name of id in the bean created and the reference name mentioned in the class A be same or not?

And another question is: how does the compiler knows that the bean of this class is mentioned in the xml if we @autowired a field.How is this linking done internally?

Comment: You could write a quick unit test to verify?

Comment: About the second question, the compiler does not know about the beans, the beans are loaded to the application context at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your bean id doesn't need to be the same as the field name in your referencing class. Injection is based on type and not on id in Spring (unless you use [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation).

The injection is provided by [Spring IoC container](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) at runtime.

Comment: Can name attribute be same for two bean creation in springs?

Comment: @mshikher 'name' attribute act as an alias of 'id', so it must be globally unique in the application context.

Answer (score 2):

The id parameter is used for qualifying beans. So it does not need to be the same as the class name. You could refer to your bean by doing:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("abc")
private B Hello
```

This is useful if you provide two beans of the same type then you can specify which one to autowire by referencing it's id with the @Qualifier annotation.
If you only have one bean of a certain type then @Qualifier's are redundant and Spring will automatically autowire this single bean whenever it is referenced without needing to know it's id.